# Generate with the help of gulp-spritesmith property of a :hover rule instead of a class selector

Tags: javascript, css, gulp, sprite, gulp-spritesmith

I am using [`gulp-spritesmith`](https://github.com/twolfson/gulp.spritesmith) to generate my sprite, and I face a problem:
I want some of the generated styles to be properties for hover rules, not for a class selectors. Adding class on mouseover event looks ugly, and I don't consider it as a solution.

For example:

```
.icon-sr_ext_icon_right {
  background-image: url(/imgs/static/external_sprite.png);
  background-position: -300px -100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.icon-sr_ext_icon_right_hovered {
  background-image: url(/imgs/static/external_sprite.png);
  background-position: -222px -200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

To be:

```
.icon-sr_ext_icon_right {
  background-image: url(/imgs/static/external_sprite.png);
  background-position: -300px -100px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.icon-sr_ext_icon_right:hover{
  background-image: url(/imgs/static/external_sprite.png);
  background-position: -222px -200px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Here is my gulp task code:

```
gulp.task('external_sprite', function() {
    var spriteData =
        gulp.src(paths.external.sprite)
            .pipe(plugins.debug( { title: "Processing image for external sprite:" } ) )
            .pipe(plugins.spritesmith({
                imgName: 'external_sprite.png',
                imgPath: '/imgs/static/external_sprite.png',
                cssName: 'external_sprite.css'
            }));

    spriteData.img.pipe(gulp.dest('./www/imgs/static/'));
    spriteData.css.pipe(gulp.dest('./' + paths.external.src)); 
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found a way how to automatically create styles for hover effects, using `sass` technology. Simply, generate sprite, than import generated css to another sass file and extend needed class:

```
@import 'external_sprite';
.icon-sr_ext_icon_right:hover {
    @extend .icon-sr_ext_icon_right_hovered;
}
```

Another way is suggested by the main contributor of the plugin in the [issue on github](https://github.com/twolfson/gulp.spritesmith/issues/18). The idea is to use `cssOpts.cssClass`:

```
cssOpts: {
  cssSelector: function (item) {
    // If this is a hover sprite, name it as a hover one (e.g. 'home-hover' -> 'home:hover')
    if (item.name.indexOf('-hover') !== -1) {
      return '.sprite-' + item.name.replace('-hover', ':hover');
    // Otherwise, use the name as the selector (e.g. 'home' -> 'home')
    } else {
      return '.sprite-' + item.name;
    }
  }
}
```

But this solution is not working if you are setting `.scss` extension of the styles file.

Comment: Great idea! But instead of importing the css i'm generating a scss sprite file but the idea remains the same

Comment: The gulp task code isn't working for me, I tried replacing cssClass with cssSelector but the entire cssOpts object is being ignored. No prefix is generated, class names end in -hover as the files do.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's hard tot tell so, could you provide your code?

Comment: Sure, this is my sprite gulp task, names of files and generated css (after it's been ran through gulp-sass): https://jsfiddle.net/b38y9b6a/

Comment: https://gist.github.com/diedsmiling/16dee22f07d817f2ec36fe113aca470f - that worked for me, I've removed retina configs from your gulp task, and changed `.scss` extension to `.css`. Here a re my images http://take.ms/v9Wjd, here is css generated: http://take.ms/Kesqa

Comment: Looks like sprites work too, it's just the scss part that is not working, simply using a .css termination makes the whole thing work, thank you. Now I need to figure out how to integrate that css with the rest of the scss

Comment: Ok, probably it's worth opening an issue on github. You can also try to use my alternative solution - extending classes with sass.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug, everything works if I just use the .css termination instead of the .scss one (retina works too). I think that's because it's cssOpts not scssOpts :)

Comment: Can the scss classes be extended all automatically, not specifically one by one? (the example seems one by one manually typed)

Comment: Issues aren't opened just for bugs :) It could be a proposal for an enhancement :) I've included them one by one, didn't had a lot of them. But I understand that it can be a problem with lots of icons. Have to think, what can be done.

Comment: Thank you for everything, without your answer I would have spent a long time figuring out why it wasn't working. I'll open an issue, thank you!

Comment: The solution to just use the generated css file instead of scss works fine for me, I guess most websites have more than one css file that get minimised and concatenated.